# What are the terms for these interest rate types?

Tags: interest-rate, terminology

I'm a beginner, so I don't know the right term for the following interest rates:

1. The interest rate between the Federal (in US) or Central bank and local banks?
2. Between banks themselves?
3. Between banks and clients (indivisual or companies)?

and are all those interests double sided? I mean if the interest between the bank and a client is 2% it would be 2% for lending and 2% for deposite?

4. Is there a term for interest between countries or between a country and international monetary fund?

Comment: Seems like a similar question as: [LIBOR and prime rate fluctuation](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/27940/14319) whose poster also asked [Difference between bank rate and prime rate](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/27155/14319)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are all those interests double sided? I mean if the interest between
> the bank and a client is 2% it would be 2% for lending and 2% for
> deposit?

The rate the bank pays people to deposit money into the bank has to be lower than the rate they charge people who borrow. This difference in the rates is how they pay the cost of the building, the computers, utilities and the like. It also is used to pay the employees salaries and benefits. It also  has to cover any losses due to bad debts. Plus the owners of the business (the banks investors) want to make a profit.

Now of course there is more than one rate paid on deposits (checking, savings, certificate of deposit), and more than one rate charged for loans (mortgage, car, signature, credit card). There can be overlap so it is possible that they may pay more for same deposits, than they charge for some loans.

Comment: A long-dated term deposit starting 20 years ago might have a higher interest rate than a home loan originated today, but on any given day, I don't think they ever offer more for any of their deposits than they charge for any of their loans. That would sound like an arbitrage risk.

Comment: A few years ago when interest rates were around 1% for a 1 one year CD, the credit union had a special 7 month CD for their 70th anniversary.  They paid 7% for those 7 months with a maximum deposit of 7K. Of course they limited the number of special CDs.

Comment: Good point. Now that you mention it, I recall special rates for kids’ accounts, but with a fairly low cap on the amounts eligible for those rates.